# Firebase Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) crashed

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add Facebook login by using firebase authentication. After successfully getting the access token, my app gets crashed at

```
SocialMediaIntegration.sharedInstance().performLogin(viewController: self) { (granterdPermission, declinedPermission, accessToken) in
        self.showHud()
        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken:accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            self.dismissHud()
            if !FireBaseAuthHandler.sharedInstance().checkIfErrorExists(error:error){
                self.showHud()
                SocialMediaIntegration.sharedInstance().getInformationFromAccessToken(token: accessToken, completionHandler: { (data) in
                    self.dismissHud()
                    guard let uid = user?.uid else{ return }
                    self.updateUserAtFirebaseWithUId(uid: uid)
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

I am getting the token successfully but signIn(with:credential) function of Firebase itself gets crashed. I am not getting further calls.

```
func performLogin(viewController:UIViewController,completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler){
    let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: viewController) { (loginResult, error) in
        if let err = error{
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }else{
            if (loginResult?.isCancelled)! == true{
                debugPrint("User cancelled login.")
            }else{
                debugPrint("accessToken:\(String(describing: loginResult?.token.tokenString))")
                completionHandler((loginResult?.grantedPermissions)!,(loginResult?.declinedPermissions)!,(loginResult?.token.tokenString)!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

crash report :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000228a20'

*** First throw call stack:
(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108e031ab __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107902f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108e83a34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108d860a8 ___forwarding___ + 1432
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108d85a88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   FocusGame IOS                       0x0000000104c5aaf1 -[FIRVerifyAssertionRequest unencodedHTTPRequestBodyWithError:] + 423
6   FocusGame IOS                       0x0000000104c54fe3 -[FIRAuthBackendRPCImplementation postWithRequest:response:callback:] + 132
7   FocusGame IOS                       0x0000000104c53f7f -[FIRAuthBackendRPCImplementation verifyAssertion:callback:] + 193
8   FocusGame IOS                       0x0000000104c52e7e +[FIRAuthBackend verifyAssertion:callback:] + 95
9   FocusGame IOS                       0x0000000104c3ad6b -[FIRAuth internalSignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:isReauthentication:callback:] + 760
10  FocusGame IOS                       0x0000000104c3a99c -[FIRAuth internalSignInWithCredential:callback:] + 135
11  FocusGame IOS                       0x0000000104c3a6e3 __43-[FIRAuth signInWithCredential:completion:]_block_invoke + 70
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c9f23f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c9f343c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c9fb95b _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1162
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c9fc2df _dispatch_queue_invoke + 336
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c9f807d _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 733
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c9ff1f9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c9fee97 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ceb75a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ceb707d start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Pods details with their versions are as follows:

- FBSDKCoreKit (4.28.0)
- FBSDKLoginKit (4.28.0)
- FBSDKShareKit (4.28.0)
- Firebase (4.6.0)
- FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.5)
- FirebaseAuth (4.3.2)
- FirebaseCore (4.0.11)
- FirebaseDatabase (4.1.1)
- FirebaseFirestore (0.9.2)
- FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.6)
- GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.12)

Comment: problem not in firebase check your method `elf.updateUserAtFirebaseWithUId(uid: uid)`

Comment: the problem is here  SocialMediaIntegration.sharedInstance().getInformationFromAccessToken(token: accessToken, completionHandler: { (data) in

Comment: I am not getting further calls, even crash occurs before SocialMediaIntegration.sharedInstance().getInformationFromAccessToken(token: accessToken, completionHandler: { (data) ) is being called.